# How do you detect names that sound similar to English words or phrases?

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, natural-language-processing

High school teachers use this Website called Kahoot to post quizzes that are answered live by the students. Students sign in to the quiz and are invited to input a name for themselves, and as you might imagine, some students have used some rather unsavory names like Phil McCraken.

As a programmer, I thought I'd research some algorithms for detecting such names. Soundex & Metaphone look fine, but these algorithms give different outputs for the names & the phrases they represent. For example, the Soundex for Phil McCraken is P452, while the phrase it sounds like is F452. Likewise, the Metaphone for Phil McCraken is FLMKKRKN, while the phrase it represents is FLMKRKN.

An idea I have: Generate Metaphones for every conceivable inappropriate phrase and store them in a list. We can check a name for inappropriateness by generating the name's Metaphone and comparing it to the Metaphones in the aforementioned list. If the name's Metaphone is only n letters off from an inappropriate phrase's Metaphone, then the name is flagged as inappropriate.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, it might be worth asking on [AI StackExchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) instead. This is usually the kind of problem handled by machine learning and statistical NLP techniques.

Comment: What's your question?  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question.  I don't see a question in the body of your post.

Comment: There seems to be an obvious problem with any scheme that contains "generate...every conceivable inappropriate phrase" as a step.  What are your requirements?  Are you looking for a solution that can be implemented in practice?  If so, do you believe it is possible to identify every conceivable inappropriate phrase?

Comment: @D.W. I meant to say "think of a bunch of inappropriate phrases."

Comment: So the idea is to create an algorithm that can detect if a name is supposed to be a euphemism, if you will, for something worthy of being forced to wash your mouth out with soap. For example, "Phil McCraken" is technically a real name, but is often used as a phonetic substitute for "fill my (spoken as 'muh') crack, in"

Comment: @D.W. As to your other questions - yes, a solution that can be implemented in practice might be nice, but I don't know if you could identify every conceivable inappropriate phrase.